Does "G contains $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as minor iff it contains $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as topological minor" say Wagner and Kuratowski Theorems are equivlnt?
Is the affirmation that " A graph contains $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as minor iff it contains $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as topological minor" also a way of saying that Wagner and Kuratowski theorems are equivalent?

Informally? Certainly. Formally? Then first you have to say what it means for two true statements to be equivalent in a way that's not silly.

Wagner's Theorem. A Graph $G$ is planar if and only if it does not contain $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a minor.
Kuratowski's Theorem. A Graph $G$ is planar if and only if it does not contain $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a topological minor.
Your proposition. A graph $G$ contains $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as minor if and only if it contains $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as topological minor.
Note that using your proposition, you can prove Wagner's Theorem assuming Kuratowski's theorem and vice versa. So, yes, your proposition indeed implies that Wagner's Theorem and Kuratowski's theorem are equivalent.
If $H$ is a topological minor of $G$ then $H$ is also a minor of $G$ but the converse is not true. So, topological minor is a more restrictive/stronger containment notion. In general, if you have two statements like:

A graph $G$ has the property $X$ if and only if it does not contain any graph in $\mathcal{G_1}$ as a (some weaker containment notion).
A graph $G$ has the property $X$ if and only if it does not contain any graph in $\mathcal{G_2}$ as a (some stronger containment notion).

Then, one would expect $\mathcal{G_2}$ to be a bigger list than $\mathcal{G_1}$ and in fact that is the case for many properties. The fact that for planarity, the size is exactly two for both these containment notions is just a coincidence.
